# gitlabci: add a job id on artifacts files

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'd like to add a build signature by the end of a file name in artifacts. I could be job id or a combination of job id and commit reference.
At the moment I get `image.slp` but I prefer to get something like `image.1.slp` or `image.1.e8f8c4ed.slp` . Here is my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
build-runner:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./build.sh
    - cp ../output/image.slp .
  artifacts:
    paths:
       - image.slp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be be able to accomplish that by means of **CI_JOB_ID** Environment variable.

Refer to [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html) for a comprehensive list of available variables that you can use.

Probably something like this could solve your problem:

```
build-runner:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./build.sh
    - cp ../output/image.slp image.$CI_JOB_ID.slp
  artifacts:
    paths:
       - image.$CI_JOB_ID.slp
```